# LNK prob. Wrapping MFC Application with /clr

Tags: c++, .net, mfc, clr

I have a problem writing wrapper program to use vendor's library in .Net client program(C#).
What the vendor provided are C++ header file and MFC static library file(.lib) built on both release and debug.
The problem is, when I build wrapper program, Visual Studio 2012 spits LNK error out like this:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___argc  nafxcwd.lib(appcore.obj)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___argv  nafxcwd.lib(appcore.obj)
```

I set up build property with option `/clr`,
set runtime library as `Multi-threaded debug DLL (/MDd)`,
set using MFC as `MFC in shared DLL`,
ignored libraries(nafxcwd.lib;msvcrtd.lib;msvcmrtd.lib;libc.lib;libcmt.lib;msvcrt.lib;libcd.lib;libcmtd.lib, [see this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wtdswk0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)),
added dependencies(nafxcwd.lib;msvcrtd.lib;msvcmrtd.lib;(vendor's library), for CRT, MFC library order).

What I missed?
I don't know I described enough. If something is ambiguous, please ask to me.
Thanks in advance!

ps. I'm very new to C++(even Visual Studio..). I'm more familiar with Java.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/166504

Comment: I check it, but I don't know what I missed :(

Comment: Did you checked build configuration of both, say if you are adding release version of lib, you should build your wrapper in release configuration

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, I checked it. And I found that there was no error when I build in release configuration without any ignore libraries! (There was same LNK2001 problem when I ignored above(libcmt.lib etc.) libraries) However, in debug configuration, whether ignore libraries or not, there is still problem.

Comment: ok hope you are knows it ,still for my clarification; use debug version of lib (probably LibName*d*.lib).

Comment: I set up again from the bottom, but there was no difference. In debug configuration, I added dependency 'libraryD.lib', and in release configuration, I added dependency 'library.lib'. I think I should ask to the vendor. Thank you anyway for your concern!